# How to figure out why my app is crashing?

Tags: ios, crash

I have an iOS app that is on the app store at the moment. It works fine, just as expected, on 99% of the Apple devices.

However, there are some devices where it opens once, flashes, and then closes again after first use.

I don't think it is a device specific issue as this was experienced on iPhones 5 and 6S plus and at the same time it works perfectly fine on other iPhone 5 and 6Ss. Similarly, same thing on the software as well (it is upto date with 11 and crashes on 11 and crashed on previous versions as well).

How can I figure out why this is happening?

[image]

This is the error :
[image]

If I was to replace it with this code, how would I know if it works :

```
 switch tempDayHolder
                    {
                    case "Monday":
                        outputWeekdays.append(2)
                    case "Tuesday":
                        outputWeekdays.append(3)
                    case "Wednesday":
                        outputWeekdays.append(4)
                    case "Thursday":
                        outputWeekdays.append(5)
                    case "Friday":
                        outputWeekdays.append(6)
                    case "Saturday":
                        outputWeekdays.append(7)
                    case "Sunday":
                        outputWeekdays.append(1)
                    default :
                        outputWeekdays.append(1)
                    }
```

Comment: Any crash log should be helpful...

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? I would also suggest to check what [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/summary) is.

Comment: If you connect your Apple Id to Xcode with the same account you publish an app to the app store, you will be able to see crash reports. See Xcode -> Window -> Organize.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. So the crash only happens on some devices and not all. I've put a screenshot from the Organize window in the original question. Where do I start looking from now? I had a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html and seem a bit lost. Sorry. Thank you

Comment: Clicking the big blue "Open in Project…" button should take you right to the offending line.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have updated the original question with screenshots and new code. The reason why I ask how do I know if it will work is because the current code didn't give me any compilation errors. Only when users ran it on their phones is when it crashed. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a better way to have multiple if statement checks please ? Thanks.